# periodically refresh events in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In the documentation of arshaw's full calendar, I found the method I think, I need to use: `.fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' )` but since I'm totally unfamiliar with JavaScript, I don't have a plan on how to use this function.

I'd like to know a simple way to make the calendar reload the events from the event sources and rerender them periodically (e.g. every 30 seconds).

Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use setInterval function : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
setInterval(function(){$('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')}, 30000);
```